# removing duplicate elements from int array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, integer

I am trying to remove duplicate elements from this array by the following code it gives me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Index 13 out of bounds for length 13  at pro2.Main.main(Main.java:36)

the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = { 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 7 };

    Integer[] o = new Integer[x.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        o[i] = Integer.valueOf(x[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; i < x.length; j++) {
            if (o[i] == o[j]) {
                o[j] = null;
             }  
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {    
         if(o[i]!=null)
          System.out.print(o[i]);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is line 36 ?

Comment: In the inside for loop, change the exit condition from `i<x.length` to `j<x.length`

Comment: You should leanr to use a debugger^^

Comment: @azro this is line 36 << if (o[i] ==o[j])

Comment: Use the languages features instead.  Sets.newSet(2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 7).forEach(System.out::print);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
        for(int j = i+1 ; i<x.length ; j++) {
                          ^ this should be j
```

The current (erroneous) loop doesn't stop until it runs past the end of the array.
As a result you are trying to get the value of x[12+1] which is x[13], Out of Array bounds.